# Firebase fetch multiple results

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift2

I was wondering if there is any way with swift and firebase, to get multiple numbers from the same child? and average all the numbers.

Example,
Every authorized user saves a number to the database. Then when they look at there number in a saved section it averages all other users numbers and compares it against theres.

I can get all the data to save, and I can get the data to send back info, but it only sends one number from the list

I have tried different ways but I can't get it to work. Any help would be awesome.

I would post some code but none of it is working real well

Thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you would use `childByAutoID` to create a random unique identifier for your user. To get multiple values from one child you would use a comma, when setting the childs value. Like this,

```
    struct getInput {
    var inputType: String!
    }
    //copying and pasting this code into your code will not work, however 
    //you should be able to understand why and how this works.

    let getUsername = getInput(inputType: usernameTextField.text!)
    let getPassword = getInput(inputType: passwordTextField.text!)

    let userReference = database.reference().child("users")
    userReference.setValue(getUsername.inputType)
    let childByAutoID = userReference.childByAutoId()
    childByAutoID.setValue(["username": getUsername.inputType, "password": getPassword.inputType])
```